# Android: Once I disable scrollingviewbehavior programmatically I can't enable it again

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

as per my requirement when I open drawerLayout at that time I want to disable scrolling behavior and when I close drawerLayout then I want to enable it. I can disable scrolling behavior when I open drawerLayout but can't enable it when closing adrawerLayout.

Below is my code for that

```
DrawerLayout mdrawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mdrawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mdrawer_layout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
                AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);

                /*AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                params.setScrollFlags(0);*/

                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
                appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(null);
                appbar.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
                AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
                FrameLayout frameContainer = (FrameLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.frameContainer);

                /*AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                params.setScrollFlags(params.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
                toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);*/

                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) frameContainer.getLayoutParams();
                appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior());
                frameContainer.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);

                appBarLayoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
                appBarLayoutParams.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior());
                appbar.setLayoutParams(appBarLayoutParams);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            }
        });
```

And my layout file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

for locking you can do this:

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

and for unlock :

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);`

Comment: I am not talking about drawerLayout. I can't enable scrolling behavior of CoordinatorLayout programmatically once i disable it.